# Flutter: Lost data in a screen when navigate back to the screen

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, persistence

I am new in Flutter/Dart. I come back to you with the following problem:

I have an empty screen with just one button in the right side of the AppBar. I come to this screen from the homepage() by navigating. When I clic the button, a form is opened in which I have to input 3 data: a date, a number and a string. When I submit these data, I close the form then I create a Card() widget to display in a GridView (in 2 columns). My problem is when I go back to the homepage and come again to the famous screen, the GridView with the data are lost: the screen is empty. I would like to keep the data in the GridView all the time the app is running. How can I do that?

If needed I can send the code.

Thank you for help.
A.KOTE

Answer (score 0):

You can declare variable to hold GridView data at homepage, and when ever you want to show the GridView, just pass the data to GridView and everything will working now

Comment: Thank you Teddichiiwa for the feedback.

Comment: Just do it and let me know the result

Comment: Hi, not working. Can you try to write an example? I do not know how to pass data from homepage to another screen, modify them (data I received from form input must be added to the list which items will be displayed in a GridView) and send it back to main() for data persistance.